# Science fiction novel titled "Brain One" involving generalised mind-reading abilities and their effects on society

Tags: story-identification, novel

The novel is titled "Brain One" and is about the evolution of people's ability to read minds and the effect it has on society, especially on politics where the deceit and secret despising of leaders for the common man is exposed.  Who is the author?

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Brain&type=Fiction+Titles - Not Found

Answer (score 2):

Might it be [Julian Ross](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30114527-brain-one)? I haven't found a page with a review or contents of the book yet, but I figured maybe you'd recognize the cover.

[image: Front cover of Brain One]